# Carregar Javascript de uma URL através da barra de endereços ou Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, userscripts

tenho alguns Userscripts e gostaria de rodar em meu Windows Phone, porém não existe nenhum app para WP como Greasemonkey ou Tampermonkey.

Então me surgiu uma idéia meio louca mas acredito que vai dar certo: Criar um bookmarklet que quando chamo baixa o Userscript salvo em algum servidor e o executa.

Para testar no WP criei um bookmark com o "URL": `javascript:alert(location.href);`, e quando chamo este bookmark ele me exibe o endereço do site atual no Alert, blz.

Então a idéia seria +- esta:

```
javascript:$.get("http://x.com/userscript.js", function(data, status){ //Aqui faria a "execução" o código baixado });
```

Bom como sempre tem um porém, eu não sei como eu faço para executar o código que foi baixado, alguém pode me dar alguma ideia?

Grato!

Comment: Dá pra rodar o Firefox no WP? Hoje em dia dá pra instalar add-ons no FF mobile

Answer (score 2):

Código descompactado:

```
javascript:-function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = "http://x.com/userscript.js";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}()
```

Comment: No desktop tudo certo! no WP agora acho que é só eu ajustar os Userscripts, muito obrigado!!